# PHP : str_replace in PHP with removing extra symbols in string

Tags: php, rss, str-replace, feed

Currently I want to pass links to my RSS feed parser from my postgreSQL database.

So far I was able to convert to an array of a single string the string reads like:

```
{"(\"(http://www.delawareriverkeeper.org/rss.xml)\")","(\"(http://www.littoralsociety.org/index.php?format=feed&type=rss)\")","(\"(\"\"http://www.nj.gov/dep/newsrel/newsrel.rss \"\")\")"}
```

Only one string.

We want to remove the extra parantheses, quotes, backslashes and brackets so it reads like "http://www.delawareriverkeeper.org/rss.xml", "http://www.littoralsociety.org/index.php?format=feed&type=rss" and so on.

We then plan splitting that into another array to pass into our parser.

I think str_replace is what I am looking for but I am having trouble of actually figuring out what to use to remove the extra quotes.

Comment: I guess you don't need to clean and the put into an array, you can achieve the same in one step with a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex matches any url into an array, so there's no need to "***splitting that into another array to pass into our parser***"

```
<?php
$subject= '{"(\"(http://www.delawareriverkeeper.org/rss.xml)\")","(\"(http://www.littoralsociety.org/index.php?format=feed&type=rss)\")","(\"(\"\"http://www.nj.gov/dep/newsrel/newsrel.rss \"\")\")"}';  
preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?):\/\/|www\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/ix', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($result[0])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.delawareriverkeeper.org/rss.xml
    [1] => http://www.littoralsociety.org/index.php?format=feed&type=rss
    [2] => http://www.nj.gov/dep/newsrel/newsrel.rss
)
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/Pu2KVH)

Comment: We noticed an error with Jeff's method. What happened was passing it into our XML parser we got an error of a non-object. I guess all the cleans and then we iterated over it to trim the double quotes off caused an error. But your regex worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Just up late trying to finish this.

Answer (score 0):

this seems trivial. have you tried?

```
<?php

$raw = '{"(\"(http://www.delawareriverkeeper.org/rss.xml)\")","(\"(http://www.littoralsociety.org/index.php?format=feed&type=rss)\")","(\"(\"\"http://www.nj.gov/dep/newsrel/newsrel.rss \"\")\")"}';

$clean = str_replace('\"', '', $raw);
$clean = str_replace(')', '', $clean);
$clean = str_replace('(', '', $clean);
$clean = str_replace('}', '', $clean);
$clean = str_replace('{', '', $clean);
$clean = str_replace(' ', '', $clean);

echo $clean;
```

> "http://www.delawareriverkeeper.org/rss.xml","http://www.littoralsociety.org/index.php?format=feed&type=rss","http://www.nj.gov/dep/newsrel/newsrel.rss"

Comment: Thank you for your help. Was in a rush to get this done by tonight explains the lackluster trial and error about the question. I know how to do this in java, but php eluded me a bit.